Use ABP permission checker DI on model
Into my project.Domain module I have a model where I want to get some info depending if it has permissions or not, so this is my relevant code:
namespace MyProject.Product
{
    public class Claim : AuditedAggregateRoot<Guid>, IMultiTenant, IProcessibleType, ITransientDependency
    {
        private readonly IPermissionChecker _permissionChecker;
        
        private IList<ClaimAction> _availableActions;
      
 
        public IList<ClaimAction> AvailableActions
        {
            get => _availableActions;
        }

        public async Task RefreshAvailableActionsAsync()
        {
            _claimActions.Clear();

           ...
            else if (...)
            {
                var hasPermission = await _permissionChecker.IsGrantedAsync("MyPermission");
                if (hasPermission)
                {
                   ....
                }
            }

            _availableActions = _claimActions.ToList();
        }

        
        public Claim(..., IPermissionChecker permissionChecker)
        {
            _permissionChecker = permissionChecker 
        }


        public Claim() : base(id)
        {
        }
}

But when it try to hit this line of code:
var hasPermission = await _permissionChecker.IsGrantedAsync()...

It throws a null reference exception on the _permissionChecker, so DI fails. Do you know what I am doing wrong? is it possible to inject the permissionChecker DI into my model?

Where is your code where you register IPermissionChecker?


IPermissionChecker is implemented in the Volo.Abp.Authorization module. Can you make sure that your module is directly or indirectly depending on that module?
Are you injecting your Claim class into another class or initializing it directly? Please keep in mind that injecting entities or aggregate roots is not recommended.


try following this guide https://community.abp.io/posts/injecting-service-dependencies-to-entities-with-entity-framework-core-7.0-db6vdh4s if you are using .net 7+
